# Converting a for loop into filter_map expression

Tags: rust

I'm new to rust and trying to explore the various methods available on the types.

I'm trying to improve the CLI walkthrough using iterator methods but am struggling with `filter_map`.

```
// Create a vector of String to hold lines where the pattern was found
let mut findings: Vec<String> = Vec::new();

// BufReader created above
for line in reader.lines() {
    match line {
        Ok(pattern) => {
            if pattern.contains(&args.pattern) {
                findings.push(pattern);
            }
         },
         Err(failure) => {
             println!("No lines in buffer")
         }
    };
}
```

I'm trying to shorten this using the iterator methods available but can't seem to figure out how to use `filter_map` to return lines where the pattern matched:

```
let mut coll:Vec<String> = reader.lines()
    .filter_map(|line| line.ok())  // <-- What should go here?
    .collect();
```

I'm not sure how to add the "include lines where `pattern.contains(&args.pattern)` returns true"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `flatmap` to clear the `None` after using `ok(),` then `filter` using a predicate.

```
let mut coll: Vec<String> = reader.lines()
    .flat_map(|line| line.ok())
    .filter(|pattern| pattern.contains(&args.pattern))
    .collect();
```

Comment: `filter_map()` is fine (and better) for the `ok()`.